# Dynamically update top margin based on div height using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I'm trying to dynamically change the top margin size as the height of another div changes. The script below works but it's using the height of the body as it changes. How do I update the script to target the height of a specific div?

```
updateDivsMargins();
$(window).resize(updateDivsMargins);

function updateDivsMargins() {
    $('div.mobile-menu').each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            'margin-top': ($(this).height()),
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    updateDivsMargins();
    $(window).resize(updateDivsMargins);

    function updateDivsMargins() {
        $('div.mobile-menu').each(function () {
            $(this).css({
                'margin-top': ($('#specificDiv').height()),
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The function will iterates through all divs with the class name "mobile-menu" and sets the 'margin-top' CSS property to the height of the div with the id "specificDiv"

Comment: Thank you! This does work but the margin doesn't change as the height of the "specificDiv" changes. I need the margin to resize as the "specificDiv" resizes without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer, the margin to resize as the "specificDiv" resizes.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Hopefully these two screenshots will help. I have a header with an alert at the top. When the mobile menu is opened the code works because it accounts for the of header. But the header height changes when the alert is closed. You'll notice the gap between the menu and header in the second screenshot. This is why need the top margin to adjust as the header changes height. I hope this helps. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gGxEHeB64uEY10BqpRxT5Kmblo-Z8lN3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G6kyh3u9Z8pEt22VBLfBcuOrwKr2S2Ks/view?usp=sharing